# Error when using heroku-toolbelt: 3.43.12 on windows 7, cant run any command

Tags: python, django, windows, heroku

Whenever I run any command it gives me the following error

```
panic: mkdir U:: The specified network name is no longer available.

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x67d400, 0x12ab2800)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x331
main.must(0x7be130, 0x12ab2800)
        /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/io.go:189 +0x44
main.configHome(0x0, 0x0)
        /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/filesystem.go:66 +0
x157
main.init()
        /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/filesystem.go:27 +0
x2c6
panic: mkdir U:: The specified network name is no longer available.

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x67d400, 0x12cb2800)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x331
main.must(0x7be130, 0x12cb2800)
        /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/io.go:189 +0x44
main.configHome(0x0, 0x0)
        /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/filesystem.go:66 +0
x157
main.init()
        /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/filesystem.go:27 +0
x2c6
panic: mkdir U:: The specified network name is no longer available.

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x67d400, 0x12c527e0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x331
main.must(0x7be130, 0x12c527e0)
        /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/io.go:189 +0x44
main.configHome(0x0, 0x0)
        /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/filesystem.go:66 +0
x157
main.init()
        /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/filesystem.go:27 +0
x2c6
 !    error getting commands pid 18844 exit 2
```

I dont get it, I downloaded the windows toolbet, why is this using addresses of ubuntu, I even uninstalled it and reinstalled it again....

EDIT:

I have another git bash installed separately and when I tried to login from there it asked me to login from the cmd.exe, when I typed "start cmd" in this other git bash (which is MINGW32), it opened a new cmd and I tried the heroku commands there and it worked.......what sorcery is this!!!

SO if I start cmd.exe from normal methods hereoku commands gives me the above error, but if I start it from the mingw32 shell and type heroku it works...